# How can I connect a mongodb replicaset using mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, replicaset, flask-mongoengine

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB replicaSet using MongoEngine? I would like to connect to any available secondary server.

I can only find pyMongo examples. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to connect to a secondary server you need to [specify a read preference](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/#pymongo.read_preferences.ReadPreference) such as `SECONDARY` or `SECONDARY_PREFERRED`. Note that when reading data from a secondary you should anticipate the data is eventually consistent and may be stale (i.e. changes may not have replicated from the primary yet).

You will want to import `ReadPreference` from the base `pymongo` driver for a list of constants.  You can specify a default `read_preference` at the connection level, or per query.

Example using secondary preferred (will read from primary if secondary is not available):

```py
 from mongoengine import connect
 from pymongo import ReadPreference
 connect('mydb', host='mongodb://server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017', replicaSet='replset', read_preference=ReadPreference.SECONDARY_PREFERRED)
```

You can check if reads are going to secondaries using `mongostat --discover`.

Comment: This looks good, but how can I force the connection to use a secondary and avoid using the primary server? In the example above it will connect to the first one there is a change it is the primary server.

Comment: @rat: Sorry, missed the part about reading from secondary :). I've corrected the example.